# AlertDialog with selector

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I am trying to do a Dialog with a selector that looks exactly like this:

[image: AlertDialog with selector]

I've tried using an AlertDialog that holds a ListView, but that gives an ugly black border between the ListView and the bottom gray area. I could use a normal Dialog, but I don't want to build the bottom gray area manually.

I know that I can subclass the AlertDialog, but then I will also need to subclass the Builder and it ends up being a lot of code for such a small detail. Is there any neat way of doing this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the alert dialog builder, it has options for that. Short example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
CharSequence items[] = new CharSequence[] {"First", "Second", "Third"};
adb.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int n) {
            // ...
        }

});
adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
adb.setTitle("Which one?");
adb.show();
```

See the [dialogs doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList), section **Adding a list**.

Comment: I suggest that you make it like this     adb.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

Comment: @AbdulazizNoor Why?

Comment: @Jaec really I forget why loooool

Comment: if you give -1, none of the items selected at beginning.

Answer (score 8):

You Should Use following code to select single item. This is working code

```
CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"View PDF", "Reduce Size", "Delete PDF", "Share PDF"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select Option");
            builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.e("value is", "" + which);
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
```